# Triggering Jquery Animation from Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on [this](https://github.com/icodebuster/transition.js) page animation. I included iframe in each of the page elements like in the code below:

```
<div class="pt-page pt-page-3">3
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="50" data-goto="-1">Go to next page</button>
        <iframe src="file:///E:/Tech%20Nidarshan/Events%20Page/index2.html" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:150;" ></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-4">4
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="50" data-goto="-1">Go to next page</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-5">5
        <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="50" data-goto="-1">Go to next page</button>
    </div>
```

Here  tag  triggers the page transition. Can I trigger the transition inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the animation is a function defined inside your iframe. To call it from outside, you could give a `name` attribute to your iframe (i.e. `name="myIframe"`) and call the function that way:

```
window.myIframe.myFunction();
```

Note: In Chrome, this might not work on local files due to Same Origin Policy rules. On a server, or using Firefox, there should be no problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But my animation function is outside iframe, and i want to call it from iframe. Can it be done?

Comment: @beingkvn try calling window.parent.myFunction(); from inside.

Comment: please check the link i provided. There is a JS file that accesses "data-animation" value, If the iframe contains that data-animation then how can i access? I tried this >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015441/get-the-contents-of-a-class-inside-an-iframe-with-greasemonkey